# how to mock git.push() or git() command

Tags: java, git, junit, mockito, wiremock

I want to write a JUnit test for JGit code. In this code I have created local file and repository using JGit.

I have written JUnit test for the rest of my method using wiremock but I am getting exception for following code.

```
git.push().setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(PortalConstants.USERNAME, PortalConstants.PASSWORD)).call();
git.close();
```

I am getting this exception

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of push command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:183)
```

Is there a way I can mock push command, as I want to execute this only in my local.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional interface for JGit and mock it.

```
public class JGitTest {

    interface JGit {
        void push();
        void close();
    }

    private static class MyCustomService {
        private final JGit jGit;

        private MyCustomService(JGit jGit) {
            this.jGit = jGit;
        }

        public void execute() {
            jGit.push();
        }
    }

    private static class JGitProductionImpl implements JGit {
        @Override
        public void push() {
            //git().push();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            //git().close();
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void jgitTest() {
        JGit jGitMock = Mockito.mock(JGit.class);
        MyCustomService myCustomService = new MyCustomService(jGitMock);
        myCustomService.execute();
        Mockito.verify(jGitMock, Mockito.times(1)).push();
    }
}
```